# Erlang receive the message and print that message

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

```
-module(cooperate).
-compile(export_all).

producer(_Pid, 0) ->
    done;
producer(Pid, N) -> 
    Pid ! {producer, N},
    io:format("process ~p producing ~p~n", [self(), rand:uniform(N)]),
    producer(Pid, N-1).

consumer() ->
    receive
        {producer,Pid} ->
            timer:sleep(10),io:format("process ~p consuming ~p~n", [self(), Pid]),
            consumer()
        after 40 ->
            stopping_terminus
        end.

go() ->
    Pid = spawn(cooperate, consumer, []),
    spawn(cooperate, producer, [Pid, 3]).

Expecting:

process <x.xx.x> producing 2
process <x.xx.x> producing 100
process <x.xx.x> producing 555
process <x.xx.x> consuming 2
process <x.xx.x> consuming 100
process <x.xx.x> consuming 555
```

I successfully producing random number like 2, 100, 555.
Now, I want to sent the message to consumer and print them out.
By the code above, I can only print consuming 3,2,1 due to the producer(Pid, N-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Pid ! {producer, N},
```

sends the message `{producer, N}` to the consumer.  For example, the consumer will receive a message like `{producer, 3}`.  You should be aware that in the consumer's receive statement:

```
receive
    {producer,Pid} ->
```

`Pid` will not match a pid.  Just because you name a variable Pid, does not mean that it will actually match a pid.  A pid is its own type in erlang--it is not an integer. A pid looks like the following when printed in the shell:

```
 <0.83.0>
```

In your receive, `Pid` will actually match `N`, and `N` is not a pid, rather `N` is just an integer you pass as an argument.  Do not name variables `Pid` that do not actually match a pid.

If you want the producer to send a random number to the consumer, how would you do that?  Well, you need the producer to send a message like `{producer, SomeRandomNumber}`.  How do you do that?

```
Pid ! {producer, SomeRandomNumber}
```

If the consumer needs to distinguish between the messages that contain `N` and the messages that contain `SomeRandomNumber`, then you can send the messages like this:

```
Pid ! {producer, producer_id, N}
Pid ! {producer, rand_num, SomeRandomNumber}
```

( or even `Pid ! {producer, N, SomeRandomNumber}` )

Then in the consumer's receive statement, you can use matching to do different things for the different types of messages that the consumer receives:

```
receive
    {producer, producer_id, N} ->
        io:format("consumer ~p received message from producer ~p~n", [self(), N]),
        consumer();
    {producer, rand_num, SomeRandomNumber} ->
        io:format("consumer ~p got random number ~p~n", [self(), SomeRandomNumber]),
        consumer()
after 40 ->
    stopping_terminus
end.
```